# Managing Spring namespace schemas in Eclipse and Maven

Tags: xml, eclipse, spring, namespaces

I've been setting up Spring namespaces using `schemaLocation` in Eclipse without issue, but now I need to work without a network connection so I can't look up the the schemas from springframework.org.

I know that when I bring a Spring component using Maven, I get the schemas I need and some files that map namespace handlers. How do I set up Eclipse to use these files in such a way that everything required is in the project?

I know about the XML catalog in Eclipse, but setting this up would seem to involve lots of manual activities on any workstation I use that needs to be done every time I use a new Spring component or change versions. It seems that everything I need comes in the Spring jar, so how do I set up use this stuff instead of any external setup, so that I have everything I need to work and build in the Eclipse project itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse-based [Spring Tool Suite](http://www.springsource.org/sts) appears to be able to resolve the schemas required from the dependencies. Still checking on the details, thought I'd ping up an answer quick in case anyone needs it.

Comment: I've installed STS. However the only thing it seems to install in the XML Catalog is the dtd for spring-beans unversioned and 2.0 :-(